# How to use Listview with pull to refresh and swipe to delete

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I am using swipe to delete in my bu using [this](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) library. and Also using the swipe to refresh and for it I am using **android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout** so the design is good and all looks good when I swipe down to refresh. My list gets refresh and contents are updated.

Following is my layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true">
<com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="5.0sp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout_emptyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
        /></ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Problem :**

As I want to delete the item by using the swipe to delete , for this I have to swipe from right to left to open the menu of delete and it gets open but When I touch on it nothing happens.

I am on the result now and I think that two times of gesture are intercepting each other. I did debug and nothing my menu for deleting the item is not listening for click.

Please help I am stuck in the middle. Any suggestion you can help me with ?

Update 1

I debug the code and it is showing me following in the log when Ever I click to delete button in the menu

> D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

I think it is something that is ignoring my touch to delete the item

Answer (score 1):

The best way as here in this [answer](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView/issues/15) is to disable sweipRefreshLayout when start sweeping menu and enable it again when finish
as this code

```
list.setOnSwipeListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeStart(int position) {
            mySwipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwipeEnd(int position) {
            mySwipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps as it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">


    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

java side

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = "MySwipeListener";
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;

swipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);

swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh()
            {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRefresh called from SwipeRefreshLayout");
                yourAdapter.swipeRefresh();
                swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I will try thi s, but can you tell me what is the problem in it ?

Comment: well after lookin your code how it may help me its the same

Comment: its giving me  log when I click on the Delte menu on the list view 
 D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

```
listView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:

        break;
    case 1:
        // delete
  youListData.remove(position);
  adapter.notifydatasetchanged()
        break;
    }
    // false : close the menu; true : not close the menu
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: I have implemented it , but its not taking touch so its not coming in this section :(

Comment: but it takes touch when there is number of rows, I mean one there is single row remain , it seems like it aint taking touch but when there are multiple rows then it takes the touch

Comment: You use smart phone device or device elumator ?